# Prestashop 1.7 how to change product price color only for products with discount

Tags: php, html, prestashop

i need some help for product prices in prestashop 1.7 with discount i need current price for product with discount with different color so i need to add some code for tpl file but what is the code? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 diferent tpl for each product. Product miniature, and product page.

You can find product miniature in themes/yourTheme/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl

And product page price is in themes/yourTheme/templates/catalog/_partials/product-prices.tpl